# Getting link from a href tag Jsoup android

Tags: android, html, jsoup

i have this html code ... and i want get the link from a href it return null

```
<div class="sp-slide">
<div class="sp-layer social" data-position="topRight" data-show-transition="down" data-show-delay="400" data-horizontal="10px">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=website">
<img src="website" alt="facebook" />
</a>
<a href="website">
<img src="website" />
</a>
</div>
<ul class="sp-layer video-album" data-position="topRight" data-show-transition="down" data-show-delay="400" data-horizontal="76px">
</ul>
<a href="articles/web.html">
<img class="sp-image" src="website" />
<header class="sp-layer" data-position="topLeft" data-show-transition="right" data-show-delay="400">
<div class="meta-m">
<span>5</span>
<img src="website" alt="comments" />
<span>12341</span>
<img src="website" alt="views" />
<span>2017/04/30</span>
<img src="website" alt="date" />
</div>
</header>
<footer class="sp-layer" data-position="bottomLeft" data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="400">
<h4>some Text</h4>
<h3>
some text
</h3>
</footer>
</a>
</div>
```

so i want to access to link in

```
<a href="website">
```

my code is

masthea = doc.select("div[class='sp-slide']");
                for (Element beers : masthea) {

```
                    imm = masthea.get(beers.siblingIndex()).getElementsByTag("a").get(2).attr("href");


                    Elements elem = beers.select("footer[class='sp-layer']");
                    for (Element ele : elem) {
                        RssItem rss = new RssItem(ele.getElementsByTag("h4").text(), ele.getElementsByTag("h3").text(),beers.attr("abs.href"), beers.getElementsByClass("sp-image").attr("src"));
                        rssItemList.add(rss);

                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements links = doc.select("a"); 
     for (Element link : links) {
         String href = link.attr("href");
}
```

href would hold all the links of the page. In your case, the only link in this html file.

Comment: ... it dosn't work ... i want to access to link in <a href="website">

Comment: Still gives you null? And what do you mean access? Getting the "website" url? Getting the content? Be more specific

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem with this code :

```
beers.getElementsByTag("a").attr("abs:href")
```

this get the first a href

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=website">
```

and i have edit this string and replace :

```
"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=
```